# Include Get Password function in User Domain without violating separation of concerns

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, separation-of-concerns, design-principles

**Problem:**

I am using a Domain Driven Design architecture and I have a domain model called User as follows:

```
public class User{
    public User(string username){
        this.Username = username;
    }

    public string Username{get;set;}            
}
```

and I would like to include a GetPassword() function to the domain.

**My research:**

I know that

- storing a password in the domain is a bad practice
- entity should not have any persistence logic to retrieve the password from db

I was thinking in retrieving the password from the UserService with a function like:

```
public class UserService{
   public string GetPassword(string username){
       //logic to retrieve db from persistence layer.
   }
}
```

However, it does not seem as clean and as natural as this

```
user.GetPassword();
```

I thought on an extension class but I had to import the class every time I needed the password. Also, i read about decorator but I still do not understand the drawbacks or the gains.

Is there another way to achieve this? If the decorator pattern is the solution could you help me fit that into this specific problem?

PD: Excuse my grammar mistakes, I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Forgetting about your domain model for a moment, you're not stirring your passwords in a manner they can actually retrieved, are you?

Comment: You used a horrible example here. As soon as you use the word "password" the shutters go down on anything related to software development and people look exclusively at security. If I see a method named "GetPassword"  then the reaction is "Cowboy coder alert. Run for the hills. " I would never help you writing the code for that function, at best I would delete it.

Comment: Why do you retrieve passwords from the DB? Anyways, there's a reason why User has no access to the password. It's beyond its conocerns. Passwords are tightly related with security. You should be able to keep Users and Security separated and User never aware of the security details. That way you can change security without messing with the Users.

Comment: You are right to give the user/security/authentication problem domain it’s own bounded context, but in itself it’s not really complex or beneficial to the business. That means you shouldn’t spend too much time building sophisticated models. Just build something that gets the job done while following security best practices.

Comment: `GetPassword` should not exist. Nor should the password be stored in the database. `SetPassword`? Perhaps. But not store, and not get. You hash and salt that son of its mother and you end up with something from which not even an administrator can get the password.  How do you recover the password when the user forgot? You don't. You set up a second authentication mechanism (cough one time use token cough) via a confirmed side channel (cough email cough) and allow to set a new password. Captcha strongly encouraged. Edit: that is assuming no integration with any kind of authentication server.

Comment: @RikD you are right at saying KISS, however I have not been implenting simple security models for a while now. Security has the "unhealthy" habit of getting more complicated over time.  The solution can be as simple as a SecurityService doing all the job. However, my experience say it will fall short sooner than later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might sound naive, but the way to don't violate SoC is not doing it. Don't integrate the password with User because it belongs to another domain. Security.

In security, the counterpart of `User` could be (and often is) `Account`. `Account` and `User` are correlated.  `Account`  hold reference to the password or a set of `Credentials`. It depends on the security protocols supported. `Credentials` could be entities of the security domain too, not a mere set of strings.

The relationship between `Account` and `User` usually is 1-to-1, unless we allow shared accounts. We access the credentials (password) through this relationship. Basically, given a *user*, we look for the *account* and then the *credentials*. We can do this from the `SecurityService` rather than  `UserService`, all the`SecurityService` need is the user's identifier.

Regarding validations, if we have to validate credentials by comparison, we do it at DB level, not in memory. It's not necessary. If it's too late for you, try making credentials not accessible from other domains.

Comment: Don’t store passwords. Period.

Comment: Well, you have to store "something" to be validated with.

Comment: Best approach is to use an external authority that handles the validation.  Once the token they give you is validated to be correct, you can associate it with the appropriate user.

Comment: That is too much for the problem here. The question is not security or architecture. Otherwise I would be agree.

Comment: Besides making `UserService` into `SecurityService`, I would have `SecurityService` accept a `User` object rather than the identifier as a `string`.

Comment: Since Users and Security are different boundaries, there's nothing wrong on `SecurityService` accepting strings tho. However, I would rather suggest to accept an Account. To keep the SoC.